# Overwrite a specific field on a specific node

Tags: views, nodes

We have a content-type of 'offices' locations. There is a View that pulls all of them together and that view is used on a contact page, a buy and a representative page. It's also used on job postings as a field 'location'.

Now they want to post a job with at "TBD" location. If I add a "TBD" node type, it will then display in all of the places where that view display 'offices' is pulled.

So I need to tell Drupal "On this job posting only, show "TBD" in the location Field. That's the ideal thing ... to rewrite that field on a specific job posting. In this case, the node is specifically 11071, if that helps?

Can I use a page-node-11071.tpl.php and some function there?

Comment: Do you have also a job content type? if that is true, how do you connect the new job, TDB location and the offices?

Comment: Jose- yes, I have a job-posting content type with a 'location' field of which is tied to a 'node-reference' (the actual content-type of offices). My issue is that if I add an office content-type, then the other pages will list that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of treating this one node in a special way (there will be more job postings in the future with location TBA), you could filter out the location by adding a filter in your views that pull locations.

In you views, under "Filter criteria" click add, choose the field type of your location, choose Operator "not equal to" and Value "TBA".

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. After seeing this, it makes sense and I see my issue.. I was thinking the actual field was linked to the view... when it was a "node-reference" so seeing your answer schooled me!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want a to display the same block which lists some node information in different pages and want to avoide listing some specific nodes in some specific pages. You can make use of views filter with 'Global: PHP' and have code similar to as below :

```
if (arg(0) == 'node') {// Set your condition here.
  if ($data->nid == NID_YOU_WANT_TO_RESTRICT) {// Set the NID you want to restrict
    return TRUE;
  }
}
```

Note : To consider multiple job postings in future, you just need to set the path condition accordingly.

Hope it helps